# SQL exception: Incorrect syntax near 'Index'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have sql query:

```
INSERT into ProjectFiles (Id,ProjectId,Index) VALUES (@Id,@ProjectId,@Index)
```

But when I try to insert object, it throws exception:

> Incorrect syntax near 'Index'. If this is intended as a part of a
>   table hint, A WITH keyword and parenthesis are now required. See SQL
>   Server Books Online for proper syntax

I think it is about `Index`, because sql have command `index`. How can I say to sql, that it is my column?

Comment: "Index", or [Index]?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Index` is a key word so you have to use `[]` for it as below

```
INSERT into ProjectFiles (Id,ProjectId,[Index]) VALUES (@Id,@ProjectId,@Index)
```

Comment: Thank you, for such quick answer!

Comment: Or better yet, change the name of the column.  Using reserved words and special characters for column names is a bad idea.